# How to transform a datetime column from a `Non UTC` format to `UTC` format without loosing data the days in which there is a time change in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df1` with a `datetime` column in format `UTC`. I need to merge this dataframe with the data frame `df2` by the column `datetime`. My problem is that `df2` is in `Europe/Paris` format, and when I transform `df2$datetime` from `Europe/Paris` to `UTC` format, I lose or duplicate data at the moments in which is the time change between either summer/winter or winter/summer. As an example:

```
df1<- data.frame(datetime=c("2016-10-29 22:00:00","2016-10-29 23:00:00","2016-10-30 00:00:00","2016-10-30 01:00:00","2016-10-30 02:00:00","2016-10-30 03:00:00","2016-10-30 04:00:00","2016-10-30 05:00:00","2016-03-25 22:00:00","2016-03-25 23:00:00","2016-03-26 00:00:00","2016-03-26 01:00:00","2016-03-26 02:00:00","2016-03-26 03:00:00","2016-03-26 04:00:00"), Var1= c(4, 56, 76, 54, 34, 3, 4, 6, 78, 23, 12, 3, 5, 6, 7))
df1$datetime<- as.POSIXct(df1$datetime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H", tz= "UTC")
df2<- data.frame(datetime=c("2016-10-29 22:00:00","2016-10-29 23:00:00","2016-10-30 00:00:00","2016-10-30 01:00:00","2016-10-30 02:00:00","2016-10-30 03:00:00","2016-10-30 04:00:00","2016-10-30 05:00:00","2016-03-25 22:00:00","2016-03-25 23:00:00","2016-03-26 00:00:00","2016-03-26 01:00:00","2016-03-26 02:00:00","2016-03-26 03:00:00","2016-03-26 04:00:00"), Var2=c(56, 43, 23, 14, 51, 27, 89, 76, 56, 4, 35, 23, 4, 62, 84))
df2$datetime<- as.POSIXct(df2$datetime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H", tz= "Europe/Paris")

df1
              datetime Var1
1  2016-10-29 22:00:00    4
2  2016-10-29 23:00:00   56
3  2016-10-30 00:00:00   76
4  2016-10-30 01:00:00   54
5  2016-10-30 02:00:00   34
6  2016-10-30 03:00:00    3
7  2016-10-30 04:00:00    4
8  2016-10-30 05:00:00    6
9  2017-03-25 22:00:00   78
10 2017-03-25 23:00:00   23
11 2017-03-26 00:00:00   12
12 2017-03-26 01:00:00    3
13 2017-03-26 02:00:00    5
14 2017-03-26 03:00:00    6
15 2017-03-26 04:00:00    7

df2
              datetime Var2
1  2016-10-29 22:00:00   56
2  2016-10-29 23:00:00   43
3  2016-10-30 00:00:00   23
4  2016-10-30 01:00:00   14
5  2016-10-30 02:00:00   51
6  2016-10-30 03:00:00   27
7  2016-10-30 04:00:00   89
8  2016-10-30 05:00:00   76
9  2017-03-25 22:00:00   56
10 2017-03-25 23:00:00    4
11 2017-03-26 00:00:00   35
12 2017-03-26 01:00:00   23
13 2017-03-26 02:00:00    4
14 2017-03-26 03:00:00   62
15 2017-03-26 04:00:00   84
```

When I change df2$datetime format from `Europe/Paris` to `UTC`, this happens:

```
library(lubridate)
df2$datetime<-with_tz(df2$datetime,"UTC")

df2
              datetime Var2
1  2016-10-29 20:00:00   56
2  2016-10-29 21:00:00   43
3  2016-10-29 22:00:00   23
4  2016-10-29 23:00:00   14
5  2016-10-30 00:00:00   51
6  2016-10-30 02:00:00   27 # Data at 01:00:00 is missing
7  2016-10-30 03:00:00   89
8  2016-10-30 04:00:00   76
9  2017-03-25 21:00:00   56
10 2017-03-25 22:00:00    4
11 2017-03-25 23:00:00   35
12 2017-03-26 00:00:00   23
13 2017-03-26 00:00:00    4 # There is a duplicate at 00:00:00
14 2017-03-26 01:00:00   62
15 2017-03-26 02:00:00   84
16 2017-03-26 03:00:00   56
```

Is there another way to transform `df2$datetime` from `Europe/Paris` format to `UTC` format that allows me to merge two data frames without this problem of having either lost or duplicated data? I don't understand why I have to lose or duplicate info in `df2`.

Is the transformation I did right in `df2$datetime` in order to merge this data frame with `df1`? What I've done so far to solve this is to add a new row in `df2` on 2016-10-30 at 01:00:00  that is the mean between `2016-10-30 00:00:00`and `2016-10-30 02:00:00` and to remove one row on 2017-03-26 at 00:00:00.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my original `df2` should be like this:

```
df2
              datetime Var1
1  2016-10-29 22:00:00    4 # This is time in format "GMT+2". It corresponds to 20:00 UTC
2  2016-10-29 23:00:00   56 # This is time in format "GMT+2". It corresponds to 21:00 UTC
3  2016-10-30 00:00:00   76 # This is time in format "GMT+2". It corresponds to 22:00 UTC
4  2016-10-30 01:00:00   54 # This is time in format "GMT+2". It corresponds to 23:00 UTC
5  2016-10-30 02:00:00   34 # This is time in format "GMT+2". It corresponds to 00:00 UTC
6  2016-10-30 02:00:00    3 # This is time in format "GMT+1". It corresponds to 01:00 UTC
7  2016-10-30 03:00:00    4 # This is time in format "GMT+1". It corresponds to 02:00 UTC
8  2016-10-30 04:00:00    6 # This is time in format "GMT+1". It corresponds to 03:00 UTC
9  2016-10-30 05:00:00   78 # This is time in format "GMT+1". It corresponds to 04:00 UTC
10 2017-03-25 22:00:00   23 # This is time in format "GMT+1". It corresponds to 21:00 UTC 
11 2017-03-25 23:00:00   12 # This is time in format "GMT+1". It corresponds to 22:00 UTC 
12 2017-03-26 00:00:00    3 # This is time in format "GMT+1". It corresponds to 23:00 UTC 
13 2017-03-26 01:00:00    5 # This is time in format "GMT+1". It corresponds to 00:00 UTC 
14 2017-03-26 03:00:00    6 # This is time in format "GMT+2". It corresponds to 01:00 UTC 
15 2017-03-26 04:00:00    7 # This is time in format "GMT+2". It corresponds to 02:00 UTC 
16 2017-03-26 05:00:00   76 # This is time in format "GMT+2". It corresponds to 03:00 UTC
```

However, my original `df2` doesn't have duplicated or lost time data. It is like this:

```
df2
              datetime Var1
1  2016-10-29 22:00:00    4
2  2016-10-29 23:00:00   56
3  2016-10-30 00:00:00   76
4  2016-10-30 01:00:00   54
5  2016-10-30 02:00:00   34
6  2016-10-30 03:00:00    3
7  2016-10-30 04:00:00    4
8  2016-10-30 05:00:00    6
9  2017-03-25 22:00:00   78
10 2017-03-25 23:00:00   23
11 2017-03-26 00:00:00   12
12 2017-03-26 01:00:00    3
13 2017-10-30 02:00:00    5
14 2017-03-26 03:00:00    6
15 2017-03-26 04:00:00    7
16 2017-03-26 05:00:00   76
```

When I applied the R code `df2$datetime<-with_tz(df2$datetime,"UTC")`, this happens:

```
df2
              datetime Var1
1  2016-10-29 20:00:00    4
2  2016-10-29 21:00:00   56
3  2016-10-29 22:00:00   76
4  2016-10-29 23:00:00   54
5  2016-10-30 00:00:00   34
6  2016-10-30 02:00:00    3 # I have to add mannually a new row between the times "00:00" and "02:00"
7  2016-10-30 03:00:00    4
8  2016-10-30 04:00:00    6
9  2017-03-25 21:00:00   78
10 2017-03-25 22:00:00   23
11 2017-03-25 23:00:00   12
12 2017-03-26 00:00:00    3
13 2017-10-30 01:00:00    5 # I have to remove mannually one of the rows refered to the time "01:00".
14 2017-03-26 01:00:00    6
15 2017-03-26 02:00:00    7
16 2017-03-26 03:00:00   76
```

If my original `df2` had one duplication at "02:00:00" on 30th Octover and a gap on 26th March between "01:00" and "03:00", I would get with the R code `df2$datetime<-with_tz(df2$datetime,"UTC")` this:

```
df2
              datetime Var1
1  2016-10-29 20:00:00    4
2  2016-10-29 21:00:00   56
3  2016-10-29 22:00:00   76
4  2016-10-29 23:00:00   54
5  2016-10-30 00:00:00   34
6  2016-10-30 00:00:00    3 # I just have to change "00:00:00" for "01:00"
7  2016-10-30 02:00:00    4
8  2016-10-30 03:00:00    6
9  2016-10-30 04:00:00   78
10 2017-03-25 21:00:00   23
11 2017-03-25 22:00:00   12
12 2017-03-25 23:00:00    3
13 2017-03-26 00:00:00    5
14 2017-03-26 01:00:00    6
15 2017-03-26 02:00:00    7
16 2017-03-26 03:00:00   76
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#As there are some Versions of df2 I use the one shown in the Question
df2 <- read.table(text = "
              datetime Var2
1  '2016-10-29 22:00:00'   56
2  '2016-10-29 23:00:00'   43
3  '2016-10-30 00:00:00'   23
4  '2016-10-30 01:00:00'   14
5  '2016-10-30 02:00:00'   51
6  '2016-10-30 03:00:00'   27
7  '2016-10-30 04:00:00'   89
8  '2016-10-30 05:00:00'   76
9  '2017-03-25 22:00:00'   56
10 '2017-03-25 23:00:00'    4
11 '2017-03-26 00:00:00'   35
12 '2017-03-26 01:00:00'   23
13 '2017-03-26 02:00:00'    4
14 '2017-03-26 03:00:00'   62
15 '2017-03-26 04:00:00'   84
", header = TRUE)

library(lubridate)

#When you define now the timezone the content of df2 is already changed
df2$datetimeEP <- as.POSIXct(df2$datetime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H", tz= "Europe/Paris")
#df2[13,]
#              datetime Var2          datetimeEP
#13 2017-03-26 02:00:00    4 2017-03-26 01:00:00

#For me it looks like that your recorded times don't consider "daylight savings time".
#So your have to uses e.g. "Etc/GMT-1" instead of "Europe/Paris"
df2$datetimeG1 <- as.POSIXct(df2$datetime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H", tz= "Etc/GMT-1")
data.frame(datetime=df2$datetime, utc=with_tz(df2$datetimeG1,"UTC"))
#              datetime                 utc
#1  2016-10-29 22:00:00 2016-10-29 21:00:00
#2  2016-10-29 23:00:00 2016-10-29 22:00:00
#3  2016-10-30 00:00:00 2016-10-29 23:00:00
#4  2016-10-30 01:00:00 2016-10-30 00:00:00
#5  2016-10-30 02:00:00 2016-10-30 01:00:00
#6  2016-10-30 03:00:00 2016-10-30 02:00:00
#7  2016-10-30 04:00:00 2016-10-30 03:00:00
#8  2016-10-30 05:00:00 2016-10-30 04:00:00
#9  2017-03-25 22:00:00 2017-03-25 21:00:00
#10 2017-03-25 23:00:00 2017-03-25 22:00:00
#11 2017-03-26 00:00:00 2017-03-25 23:00:00
#12 2017-03-26 01:00:00 2017-03-26 00:00:00
#13 2017-03-26 02:00:00 2017-03-26 01:00:00
#14 2017-03-26 03:00:00 2017-03-26 02:00:00
#15 2017-03-26 04:00:00 2017-03-26 03:00:00

#You can use "dst" to see if datetime of a time zone has "daylight savings time"
dst(df2$datetimeEP)
dst(df2$datetimeG1)
dst(with_tz(df2$datetimeEP,"UTC"))
dst(with_tz(df2$datetimeG1,"UTC"))

#If your recorded times consider "daylight savings time" then you HAVE a gap and an overlap.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply user10488504! The original df2 I work with has datetime in the format "Local Time", what in my case means "GTM+2" in summer and "GTM+1" in winter. That is, in summer we have two hours of difference between our local time and UTC time, and in winter the difference is one hour. The time change between summer (GTM+2) and winter is on 30th at 03:00, when the time return at 02:00 again. So, theoretically, on 30th October we have the time "02:00:00" twice. This day "has" 25 hours.

Comment: In March we change the local time from "GTM+1" to "GTM+2" again on 26th March. This day, when we reach 02:00:00, we change our clocks automatically to 03:00:00. So this day "has" only 23 hours. As I said, my original `df2` doesn't reflect this (it doesn't have neither duplicates on 30th October 2016 nor gaps on 26th March 2017), and I don't know why. I don't know if the original 'df2' I'm working with is wrong or it is just in a way that I don't understand and there is a way to transform it to UTC properly.

Comment: In your answer either before and after 30th October and 26th March the difference between UTC and my local time is one hour, and as I already explained you, that's not my case.

Comment: In your answer either before and after 30th October and 26th March, the difference between UTC and my local time is one hour, and that's not my case. As I explained in my own answer, the point is that when I apply the R code "df2$datetime<-with_tz(df2$datetime,"UTC")" to my dataset, it works perfectly (considering a time difference of 2 hours in summer and one in winter), but it fails in a small detail: there is a time gap between "00:00" and "02:00" on 30th October and a duplicated time at "01:00" on 26th March. I wouldn't expect this after transforming to UTC, would I?

Comment: As I also explained in my answer, if I add in my original 'df2' one duplicated on 30th October and a gap on 26th March 2017, the result after running the R code "df2$datetime<-with_tz(df2$datetime,"UTC")" would be closer to what I think should be the correct result. So I don't know what is going on. I don't know if either my original df2 should have a duplicated time on 30th October and a gap on 26th March or if there is a way to transform my df2 that I don't know.

Comment: If df2 follow the time change of your local time the timestamps in df2 NEED TO HAVE duplicates on 30th October 2016 and gaps on 26th March 2017 (as shown in your answer) but it doesn't. So it looks like the timestamps in df2 do NOT follow the time change of your local time - what makes sense as otherwise you could not distinguish between the observations on 30th October 2016 at 2:00-3:00. You only have to figure out if df2 runs on "GTM+1" or on "GTM+2". (Most probably it runs on GTM+1.)

Comment: I will investigate it!! Thanks!!